# Get nested JSON to be pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I have this JSON,

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "symbol": "TSLA",
      "price": [
        {
          "date": "2021-10-19",
          "close": 141.98
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "symbol": "AMZN",
      "price": [
        {
          "date": "2021-10-19",
          "close": 3444.15
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to create two pandas dataframe from the first array and second array based on the `price` without using the stock name to identify it.

Expected:

First array (which is based on TSLA), df1

```
    date      close
2021-10-19   141.98
```

Second array (which is based on AMZN), df2

```
    date      close
2021-10-19   3444.15
```

I had explored `json_normalize` function from pandas but it seem like it can only flatten first level of a JSON. How can I flatten the second layer and only get my expected result?

EDIT:

Managed to somewhat get it to work, less not my expected result totally. Using this,

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['stocks'], record_path='price', meta=['symbol'])
```

It returns

```
    date      close    symbol
2021-10-19   141.98    TSLA
2021-10-19   3444.15   AMZN
```

Is there a way to make the two stocks split when performing the `json_normalize` like what my expected result suppose to be?

Comment: Why do you need two dataframes?  That doesn't seem to make sense.  You can certainly do `df1 = df[df'symbol']=='TSLA'` and `df2 = df[df['symbol']=='AMZN']`.

Comment: The line of code will be run without knowing the symbol name in the JSON, therefore I cannot hard code the symbol name in what you proposed. The idea is to get the df based on the first array and the second array of each without needing to know the names (if i make any sense).

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
df = df.set_index('symbol')
```

Then just call

```
df.loc['TSLA']
```

Or you can do

```
d = {x : y for x ,y in df.groupby(df.index)}
d[0]
d[1]
```